# Simple way to solve a system of linear equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for an easy and fast solution to the following problem: I have three 3D vectors `x_i`, three 3D vectors `y_i`, a 3D vector `b` and a 3x3 matrix A with coefficients a11 - a33 (that are unknown).

The relation is as follows:

```
x_i = A * y_i + b
```

That resolves to

```
x_i_1 = ( a11 * y_1_1 + a12 * y_2_1 + a13 * y_3_1 ) + b_1
```

etc.

So there are 9 equations and 9 unknown variables a11 - a33, easy peasy math. But how do I solve this system using build in Matlab functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the 9 equations and 9 unknowns, then just pretend like the 9 unknowns live in a column vector called `r`, and write the rows of a 9x9 matrix called `C` to store the coefficients. If the left-hand side of the 9 equations is also stored in a column vector `x` then you'll be solving something like

```
Cr = x
```

And this is simply done in Matlab with

```
r = C\x;
```

Now `r` stores the solution for the 9 unknowns (assuming that solutions exist, etc.)

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for, thanks. So in my case C contains a lot of zeros, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, each row only has 3 non-zero entries it appears. Also, you may need to solve for `x_i_j - b_j = ...` with that subtraction on the left hand side. Then add back the `b_j` after solving to recover the solution vector, since the `b_j` don't apply to the `a_ik` coefficients, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, C will be mostly filled with zeros.

Comment: Note the matrix left divide operator `C\x` is preferred over `inv(C) * x` because it's [never a good idea to actually calculate the inverse matrix.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/05/16/purpose-of-inv/).

Comment: @Li-aungYip Can you provide me with more information about that? I read the article but it seems to be written for people that already know *why* it's actually a bad idea to calculate inverse matrixes - my knowledge about numerical math is fairly basic, but I'm currently working with a lot of transformation matrixes, and my equations do often include inverse matrixes (4x4).

Comment: @Niko: If your matrix is badly conditioned (see *condition number*) then calculating the matrix inverse involves floating point operations between very large and very small numbers, which introduces a lot of error. Usually, though, you don't actually have to explicitly calculate the matrix inverse - you can get the same effect with the matrix division ` \ ` operator which uses a smarter algorithm and avoids computing the inverse.

Comment: It's important to note, though, that if you're in the case where the matrix is badly scaled (poor condition number) then this affects the accuracy of using *any* method to solve a linear system of equations `Ax=b`, regardless of whether you use Jacobi iterations, gradient descent, Newton's method, or plain old Gaussian elimination. If computing `inv(A)` is a numerically unstable action, then solving `Ax=b` is just going to be difficult. A more common reason to avoid computing `inv(A)` is that, for large systems, it's a memory-intensive and slow operations. Why waste that time/space?