# Need help for iterative method in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new in matlab and have little idea about iterative method. i need to solve following equation with iterative method

```
T1=(T2/R2+T3/R3+Tm/R1)/(1/R2+1/R3+1/R1)

T2=(T1/R2+T4/R4)/(1/R2+1/R4)

T3=(T1/R3)/(1/R3)

T4=(T2/R4+T5/R5+T7/R6)/(1/R4+1/R5+1/R6)

T5=(T6/R8+T4/R5)/(1/R8+1/R5)

T6=(T5/R8+T7/R10)/(1/R8+1/R10)

T7=(T4/R6+T6/R10+T8/R11)/(1/R6+1/R10+1/R11)

T8==(T7/R11+T10/R12)/(1/R11+1/R12)

T9==(T10/R13)/(1/R13)

T10==(T8/R12+T9/R13+Ta/R14)/(1/R12+1/R13+1/R14)
```

all R (resistance) values and Tm and Ta (temperature which is 30 suppose) values are known. Now I want to find temperature T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9 and T10 values with an iterative method. 
I need help to do it. thanks

Comment: Why iterative? You have a system of equations in the form Ax=b, which you can solve using x=A\b. Write out this matrix from your equation.

Comment: If you have different formulas for each Temperature then its better that you do it directly , if you have to run them all only once , in the other case please explain a bit more

Comment: Would any of these solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728636/matlab-solving-equations-problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484109/solving-system-of-equations-using-matlab http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198230/simple-way-to-solve-a-system-of-linear-equations-in-matlab